# Unistall CentOS 6 from a Win7 partition

Tags: linux, windows-7, centos

I installed centOS 6 in a separare win7 partition.  Now I want to remove/uninstall it, but I can not find out how to do it.

Comment: Simple. Delete the partition, and restore the Windows bootloader to the MBR.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot up in Windows XP/Vista/7.
2. Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management

(UAC or User Account Control in Vista/7)

3. Go to Disk Management under “Storage”
4. Select your Hard Disk and then the Linux partition.
5. Delete the Linux partition this will delete Linux and grub.
6. Now reboot your Laptop/Desktop with Windows XP start up disc or floppy and type the command “fixmbr” .
7. Above command will repair your bootloader and re-write ntldr which will replace corrupted grub.
8. Thats it done now boot your Laptop or Desktop normally it will be booted by default in Windows XP/Vista/7.

Comment: Watch out for step 6. That one's a doozy :'(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that CentOS has replaced the MBR/bootloader what you can do is

1) boot off your Windows 7 installer disc

2) When it loads up,select your language and select 'repair your computer', it will then prompt you which installation you want to repair it will then ask you if you want it to try and auto-repair, select no.

3) Select 'Startup repair' on the next screen which should solve the issue.

If the issue isn't resolved go through steps 1&2 but this time select command prompt
and type:
 bootrec.exe /FixMbr

If the command worked it should say "Command completed successfully and you can then boot into windows

To delete the centOS paritions you can simply right click my computer and click "Manage"

Click Disk management and *carefully* delete the 'unknown' partition(s) making sure it's the right ones..Optionally if you're not too sure you can always boot off a linux livedvd or livecd and run 'fdisk' and delete the linux and linux swap partitions and create a new one.

[How to fix Windows 7 MBR](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html)